# Access Point on PC not fully accessible from Mobile

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, mobile-phone

I have set up WLAN Access Point on two different machines, one running Windows XP and another running Windows 7. The two were accessible from one another and I could browse Internet over Wifi, using connection from the other.

Now problem is occurring when I try to connect to either of the PC from my Samsung Wifi enabled mobile, no connection occurs. I was able to connect to other WiFi network(setup by some third party), which indicates that there isn't any issue with my Mobile device.

My query is, is there some kind of Protocol issue that is preventing me to enter the Access Points setup?

Note: My set is [Samsung Ch@t 335](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_ch@t_335-3634.php).  I do not get any error message on the Mobile Screen, but after attempting to connect for few minutes, I get back to the list showing Available Access Points and the WiFi connection Icon doesn't show up.

***Edit: I am following instructions from [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADpHIeBSFUk) video.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of encryption do you use for your WiFi networks? I looked through the specification provided by you but didn't see if your mobile supports the modern encryption like WPA with pre-shared key or not. It might be the wrong encryption that prevents you from connecting the network. My old HTC smartphone did support only WEP and I had problems with my WiFi network at home...

Did you try just to make your access point just publicly available (no encryption at all, no MAC fitering whatsoever) and see if your mobile can dial-in?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using WEP for encryption. Actually I was following this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADpHIeBSFUk , so you can evaluate what I have done. I am using Key based connectivity but no MAC filtering at all. I will need to try public and no encryption and get back to you.

Comment: I turned off both encryption and authentication, and now I am able to connect from my mobile. Actually, form the beginning I was more interested to see If I am able to log into some wifi network using my mobile and till now, haven't been lucky enough to find one publicly available. Now I have one at home :)